# Ideas on how to beat a greedy search algorithm in maze by collecting maximum items?

Tags: graph, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, a-star, maze

First I'll explain the problem. I have a player in a closed maze filled with items that he should collect to win the game. We also have an opponent which tries to do just the same.The player with the biggest amount for items collected wins. Suppose the opponent follows a BFS algorithm to collect the items, and we have access to all its decisions for every turn, can we make some prediction on what items in the maze should we go to first (so it doesn't get a chance in having the ones close to it), or just pin point a location where items are more dense?

It feels like randomness could also affect this very badly (most of the items land next to the opponent for example). What about if the opponent follows an A* algorithm?

I have already implemented an A* algorithm for our player.First, I look for the closest item heuristically using manhattan distance, then i go collect it and look for the new closest one again and so on.I feel like the "looking for the closest item" method might not be that efficient, maybe pin pointing (somehow haha) a location where the items are more dense is better as i said.

```python
def astar(start, items, mazeMap):
  # mazeMap is a dictionary with nodes and as a key for every node 
  is associated another dictionary containing the neighbors as keys
  and the weight of edges to them as values
  # items is a list of pairs giving the location of each item

  # Apparent goal
  # goal is a pair (closest_item, distance_to_closest_item)
  goal = closest_item(start, items)

  # Set of nodes not needed to be checked anymore
  # closedSet = {node: [gscore, fscore]}
  closedSet = {}

  # Set of potential short-path nodes
  # openSet = {node: [gscore, fscore]}
  openSet = {start: [0, goal[1]]}

  # Set to construct the optimal path
  cameFrom = {}

  while len(openSet) > 0:
    # Looking for the node with the smallest fscore
    current = list(openSet.keys())[0]

    for keys, values in openSet.items():
        if values[1] < openSet[current][1]:
            current = keys

    # If the chosen node is an item of cheese, we are done
    if current in items:
        return reconstruct_path(cameFrom, current)

    # The current node no longer needs to be checked
    closedSet[current] = openSet[current]
    del openSet[current]

    for keys, values in mazeMap[current].items():

        # We don't need to check the node if it's already been done
        if keys in list(closedSet.keys()):
            continue

        # Calculate Gscore
        tentative_gscore = closedSet[current][0] + values

        if keys not in list(openSet.keys()):
            openSet[keys] = [0, 0]
        elif tentative_gscore >= openSet[keys][0]:
            continue

        # This new path is better than the previous one, save it !
        cameFrom[keys] = current
        openSet[keys][0] = tentative_gscore
        openSet[keys][1] = tentative_gscore + manhattan_distance(keys, goal[0])

  return "Impossible"
```